# How to signup user using Amazon Cognito in Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-cognito

So I am trying to make an Android application and link it with Cognito, I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cn18WTMtt9c) (that is part 3 of it where I started having issues) and everything works for him, but I got this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.homing, PID: 22346
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5979)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
>           at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5974)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
>           at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;
>           at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.(VersionInfoUtils.java:41)
>           at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:77)
>           at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.(ClientConfiguration.java:43)
>           at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool.(CognitoUserPool.java:189)
>           at com.example.homing.models.CognitoHelper.getUserPool(CognitoHelper.java:36)
>           at com.example.homing.views.SignUpActivity.signUp(SignUpActivity.java:65)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5974) 
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
>           at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.homing-5MXFtoCYU5up-qVfFklHMQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.homing-5MXFtoCYU5up-qVfFklHMQ==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]

And it takes me to this line `CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(context, userPoolID, clientID, null, cognitoRegion);`

Full class:

```
package com.example.homing.models;

import android.content.Context;

import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;

public class CognitoHelper {
private final String userPoolID = "us-east-1_jA*****";
private final String clientID = "2uo5cgvjd*********";
private final String clientSecret = "";
private final Regions cognitoRegion = Regions.US_EAST_1;
private Context context;

public CognitoHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public String getUserPoolID() {
    return userPoolID;
}

public String getClientID() {
    return clientID;
}

public String getClientSecret() {
    return clientSecret;
}

public Regions getCognitoRegion() {
    return cognitoRegion;
}

public CognitoUserPool getUserPool() {
    CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(context, userPoolID, clientID,
            null, cognitoRegion);

    return userPool;
}
```

}

(I added the stars but I do have the full ID's in the code.)

My activity button click:

```
public void signUp(View view) {
        if(passwordEdit.getText().toString().equals(confirmPasswordEdit.getText().toString())) {
            CognitoUserPool userPool = cognitoHelper.getUserPool();

            CognitoUserAttributes userAttributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();
            userAttributes.addAttribute("phone_number", phoneEdit.getText().toString());
            //userAttributes.addAttribute("picture", ); save on s3 then bring url
            userAttributes.addAttribute("name", nameEdit.getText().toString());
            userAttributes.addAttribute("birthdate", birthdayEdit.getText().toString());
            userAttributes.addAttribute("status", statusEdit.getText().toString());

            userPool.signUpInBackground(phoneEdit.getText().toString(), passwordEdit.getText().toString(),
                    userAttributes, null, signupHandler(userAttributes, userPool));
        } else {
            Log.d("AWS cognito", "Passwords dont match");
        }
    }

    private SignUpHandler signupHandler(final CognitoUserAttributes userAttributes, final CognitoUserPool userPool) {
        return new SignUpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(CognitoUser user, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) {
                if (!userConfirmed) {
                    Log.d("AWS cognito", "Signup not confirmed " + cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails.getDestination());
                } else {
                    Log.d("AWS cognito", "Signup confirmed");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                Log.d("AWS cognito", "Signup failed");
            }
        };
    }
```

As this error has been solved (see comments) I got a new issue where I get this error while signing up a user

> "A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute (Service:
>   AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   NotAuthorizedException; Request ID:
>   4336c90e-f15b-4100-bd7b-47111ef64979)"

Even though in my user pool i have write and read access for all attributes

Comment: Where’s the rest of the exception?

Comment: Looks like you’re missing the dependency indicated in the stack trace.

Comment: @DaveNewton i added those 2: 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.29' and 
'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.6.29'

Comment: Looks like you’re missing the dependency indicated in the stack trace.

Comment: @DaveNewton which one?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory"

Comment: In “the” folder... which folder is that? How are you building? Why aren’t you using gradle/maven/whatever to manage your dependencies?

Comment: @DaveNewton I added the class but the signup still fails "Unable to execute HTTP request: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)" even tho i have all permissions

Comment: @DaveNewton "A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 4336c90e-f15b-4100-bd7b-47111ef64979)", in user pool i have all attributes writable and readable